# How do you use gridbaglayout in java?

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

How do you use grid bag layout? What does it mean with all of the pady and all of that. there are no tutorials properly online.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html Writing layout by hand could be tiresome and unintuitive, but if you understand it you should be better with it.

Comment: thanks but I have looked at that and I don't really understand it. can you explain it to me?

Comment: You're joking right? What do you mean explain it to you? The tutorial is several pages long, we have no idea what part of it your don't understand. You need to write sample code and experiment. When the code doesn't work as you expect, then you post the code and maybe we can help you out. The tutorial has working examples you can start with.

Comment: @The Java Man  Sorry, I don't mean to be unhelpful, but the official tutorial seems to be pretty clear to me. If you cannot understand the first half, skim to "The Example Explained" then use the first half as a reference. Then after you get the demo, you could fiddle with it to get a better understanding. Cheers!

Comment: Alright! Thanks! I will try that. Maybe I just didn't try hard enough. Thanks for everybodys help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure about gridbaglayout but gridlayout is quite easy. You just say

```
frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(number of rows, number of columns, spacing, spacing from     top));
```

like that.

Comment: I believe that write a normal size gridlayout (say, 5*6) could already be tiresome since the last time I did it I just wanted to hit the keyboard with my mouse.

Comment: Yeah I guess you are right. I have used blank labels so many times as "spacemekers"

Answer (score 4):

Did you really search? [This](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) is a good one (and btw from official sources)

Comment: I looked at this and I didn't understand it properly. If possible can you explain it to me?

Comment: Sounds like you'd better sit down, take a breath, and work your way through it before you judge that citation as unhelpful.  What on earth do you expect someone to say that will make it clearer than the official source?

Answer (score 0):

Totally Gridbag

http://madbean.com/anim/totallygridbag/

Answer (score -2):

You could also set the layout to `null` and manually place it using the `setBounds(x, y, length, height)` method